# How to get selected option (Spring MVC + Freemarker)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have the following situation:

Freemarker:

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Get project</option>
  <#assign i = 1>
  <#list titleList as title>
  <option id="${i}" name="${i}">    
  ${title.content}    
  </option>
  <#assign i++>
   </#list>
</select>
```

How to get in Spring MVC controller selected value? I can not find information how to go about this with such a display SELECT. `model.AddAttrubute`  allows us to transfer data to a view. Forms can be associated with an object and retrieve values. But as for the SELECT I can not find anything suitable